# How can I make a camera walk animation?

Tags: animation, camera

I want to get my camera to have a walk animation. How can I do it?

It doesn't have to be complicated; I just want to make it like it's walking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it go from point A to B with some keyframes:

[image]

In the Graph Editor, select the Z location track only (press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to display this track only), and in the *N* panel, open the Modifier panel, add a *Noise* modifier, play with the *Scale* and *Strength* values (you can enable *Restrict Frame Range* option if you want the modifier to begin and/or stop at a certain frame):

[image]

Result:

[image]

If you want someting more regular, keyframe a movement on Z location and make it cyclic with a *Cycles* modifier instead (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to automatically create the modifier):

[image]